# How to write this Solr query in a more compact style?

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

Given a *white space tokenized* field containing only numbers, I want to write a query able to match the documents containing:

1) ALL the numbers in a Set A

AND

2) At least one of the numbers in a Set B

This is what I wrote

```
q=wstf:( 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 ) AND ( 5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8 )  // (Set A) AND (Set B)
```

I remember (but I might be wrong) that it is possible to specify the default operator within the expression (I'm NOT talking about the *q.op* parameter) in order to get something like

```
q=wstf:(AND 1 2 3 4) AND wstf:(OR 5 6 7 8)
```

But I cannot find anything like this in the Reference Guide.

EDIT

Please, notice I set the *default operator* to AND

Any help?

Comment: `q=wstf:(+1 +2 +3 +4) AND wstf:(5 6 7 8)` should do that.

Comment: Hang on a second! What would be the result if I set the default operator to AND ? Would the second part use a OR operator? I think not...

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to specify a default operator for combining the elements in a collection (within brackets), just one to combine different query elements (field:value). But I am always keen to learn something new ;)

Comment: I gave it a try and I noticed the default operator affects the results: count(x y) = count(+x +y) = count(x AND y) = 282 -- count(x OR y) = 738. Your suggstion would be good if I didn't change the default operator

Comment: Then what about `q=wstf:(1 2 3 4 (5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8))`?

Comment: I think it's the only way out, even if I aimed at avoiding all the boolean operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only be able to leave off the operator you specified as default, in your case AND, and combine the query in one statement:

```
q=wstf:(1 2 3 4 (5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8))
```

That is not as nice and short as you hoped to get, but at least a little bit shorter...